# Color change does not work

Tags: windows-7, colors, gtk2hs

I try to change the color of the widget using the following code:

```
widgetModifyBg w StateNormal (Color 0xffff 0xffff 0)
```

It works on ubuntu, but not under Windows.

Comment: Please provide some context to your questions. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in a folder with the program library `libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll`.